# Slick 3.0 bulk insert or update (upsert)

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick, typesafe

what is the correct way to do a bulk insertOrUpdate in Slick 3.0?

I am using MySQL where the appropriate query would be

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

[MySQL bulk INSERT or UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286452/mysql-bulk-insert-or-update)

Here is my current code which is very slow :-(

```
// FIXME -- this is slow but will stop repeats, an insertOrUpdate
// functions for a list would be much better
val rowsInserted = rows.map {
  row => await(run(TableQuery[FooTable].insertOrUpdate(row)))
}.sum
```

What I am looking for is the equivalent of

```
def insertOrUpdate(values: Iterable[U]): DriverAction[MultiInsertResult, NoStream, Effect.Write]
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are several ways that you can make this code faster (each one *should* be faster than the preceding ones, but it gets progressively less idiomatic-slick):

- Run `insertOrUpdateAll` instead of `insertOrUpdate` if on slick-pg 0.16.1+

  ```
  await(run(TableQuery[FooTable].insertOrUpdateAll rows)).sum
  ```
- Run your DBIO events all at once, rather than waiting for each one to commit before you run the next:

  ```
  val toBeInserted = rows.map { row => TableQuery[FooTable].insertOrUpdate(row) }
  val inOneGo = DBIO.sequence(toBeInserted)
  val dbioFuture = run(inOneGo)
  // Optionally, you can add a `.transactionally`
  // and / or `.withPinnedSession` here to pin all of these upserts
  // to the same transaction / connection
  // which *may* get you a little more speed:
  // val dbioFuture = run(inOneGo.transactionally)
  val rowsInserted = await(dbioFuture).sum
  ```
- Drop down to the JDBC level and run your upsert all in one go ([idea via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25675325/135978)):

  ```
  val SQL = """INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);"""

  SimpleDBIO[List[Int]] { session =>
    val statement = session.connection.prepareStatement(SQL)
    rows.map { row =>
      statement.setInt(1, row.a)
      statement.setInt(2, row.b)
      statement.setInt(3, row.c)
      statement.addBatch()
    }
    statement.executeBatch()
  }
  ```

Comment: Cool.  Thank you especially for the second technique.   I did not know about that

Comment: Just to doublecheck: the first solution is not inserting in batch, is it? It looks like it's doing all inserts in parallel bot not batched, isn't it?

Comment: In the first solution do I save the round trips to mysql server?

Comment: @ted - I do not believe so, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: +1 for `.transactionally` - this alone improved performance inserting 50,000 rows from 3 minutes to 1 minute.

Comment: Since slick-pg 0.16.1 there is a `.insertOrUpdateAll` for bulk upserts with Slick & postgresql

Comment: I dont find insertOrUpdateAll method in slick 3.3.2?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see at [Slick examples](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html#populating-the-database), you can use `++=` function to insert using JDBC batch insert feature. Per instance:

```
val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]
val rows: Seq[Foo] = ...
foos ++= rows // here slick will use batch insert
```

You can also "size" you batch by "grouping" the rows sequence:

```
val batchSize = 1000
rows.grouped(batchSize).foreach { group => foos ++= group }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think ++= does insertOrUpdate.  I believe it is just insert, and in my case will throw an integrity exception if there is a duplicate row

Answer (score 0):

use sqlu

this demo  work

```
case ("insertOnDuplicateKey",answers:List[Answer])=>{
  def buildInsert(r: Answer): DBIO[Int] =
    sqlu"insert into answer (aid,bid,sbid,qid,ups,author,uid,nick,pub_time,content,good,hot,id,reply,pic,spider_time) values (${r.aid},${r.bid},${r.sbid},${r.qid},${r.ups},${r.author},${r.uid},${r.nick},${r.pub_time},${r.content},${r.good},${r.hot},${r.id},${r.reply},${r.pic},${r.spider_time}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `aid`=values(aid),`bid`=values(bid),`sbid`=values(sbid),`qid`=values(qid),`ups`=values(ups),`author`=values(author),`uid`=values(uid),`nick`=values(nick),`pub_time`=values(pub_time),`content`=values(content),`good`=values(good),`hot`=values(hot),`id`=values(id),`reply`=values(reply),`pic`=values(pic),`spider_time`=values(spider_time)"
  val inserts: Seq[DBIO[Int]] = answers.map(buildInsert)
  val combined: DBIO[Seq[Int]] = DBIO.sequence(inserts)
  DEST_DB.run(combined).onComplete(data=>{
    println("insertOnDuplicateKey data result",data.get.mkString)
    if (data.isSuccess){
      println(data.get)
      val lastid=answers.last.id
      Sync.lastActor !("upsert",tablename,lastid)
    }else{
      //retry
      self !("insertOnDuplicateKey",answers)
    }
  })
}
```

and i try to use sqlu in a single sql but error maybe sqlu dont supply String Interpolation

this demo dont work

```
case ("insertOnDuplicateKeyError",answers:List[Answer])=>{
  def buildSql(execpre:String,values: String,execafter:String): DBIO[Int] = sqlu"$execpre $values $execafter"
  val execpre="insert into answer (aid,bid,sbid,qid,ups,author,uid,nick,pub_time,content,good,hot,id,reply,pic,spider_time)  values "
  val execafter=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `aid`=values(aid),`bid`=values(bid),`sbid`=values(sbid),`qid`=values(qid),`ups`=values(ups),`author`=values(author),`uid`=values(uid),`nick`=values(nick),`pub_time`=values(pub_time),`content`=values(content),`good`=values(good),`hot`=values(hot),`id`=values(id),`reply`=values(reply),`pic`=values(pic),`spider_time`=values(spider_time)"
  val valuesstr=answers.map(row=>("("+List(row.aid,row.bid,row.sbid,row.qid,row.ups,"'"+row.author+"'","'"+row.uid+"'","'"+row.nick+"'","'"+row.pub_time+"'","'"+row.content+"'",row.good,row.hot,row.id,row.reply,row.pic,"'"+row.spider_time+"'").mkString(",")+")")).mkString(",\n")
  val insertOrUpdateAction=DBIO.seq(
    buildSql(execpre,valuesstr,execafter)
  )
  DEST_DB.run(insertOrUpdateAction).onComplete(data=>{
    if (data.isSuccess){
      println("insertOnDuplicateKey data result",data)
      //retry
      val lastid=answers.last.id
      Sync.lastActor !("upsert",tablename,lastid)
    }else{
      self !("insertOnDuplicateKey2",answers)
    }
  })
}
```

a mysql sync tool with scala slick
https://github.com/cclient/ScalaMysqlSync